# Posting from iOs with RestKit to WCF

Tags: ios, wcf, post, restkit

**Im trying to make a post from Xcode (with RestKit) to a WCF Service. Here is my code:**

```
   NSDictionary *queryParams;
    queryParams = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                   @"1.0",@"oauth_version",
                   @"33333",@"oauth_nonce",
                   @"HMAC-SHA1",@"oauth_signature_method",
                   @"1323",@"oauth_timestamp",
                   @"rrr", @"oauth_consumer_key",
                   @"t672hpIerersdsfc", @"oauth_signature", nil];

    RKObjectManager *objectManager = [RKObjectManager sharedManager];

    RKURL *baseURL = [RKURL URLWithBaseURLString:@"http://myServer:80/appccservice.svc"];
    objectManager = [RKObjectManager objectManagerWithBaseURL:baseURL];


    objectManager.client.baseURL = baseURL;
    objectManager.client.authenticationType = RKRequestAuthenticationTypeOAuth1;
    objectManager.client.username = @"lsantos";
    objectManager.client.password = @"clave";

    NSString *resourcePath = [@"/json/post" stringByAppendingQueryParameters:queryParams];

    [RKObjectManager sharedManager].serializationMIMEType = RKMIMETypeJSON;
    RKObjectMapping *userSerialization = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[NSMutableDictionary class]];

    [userSerialization mapKeyPath:@"name" toAttribute:@"nombreNovia"];
    [userSerialization mapKeyPath:@"tel" toAttribute:@"fecha"];


    RKObjectMapping *serialize = [userSerialization inverseMapping];


    [[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider setSerializationMapping:serialize forClass:[User class]];

    [[RKObjectManager sharedManager].router routeClass:[User class] toResourcePath:resourcePath forMethod:RKRequestMethodPOST];

    User *data = [User new];
    data.nombreNovia = @"joaquin";
    data.fecha = @"4344";


    [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] postObject:data delegate:self];
```

I used the RKLogConfigureByName and got this:

Request:

```
URLRequest '<NSMutableURLRequest http://myServer:80/appccservice.svc/json/post?oauth_timestamp=32432304&oauth_nonce=123123&oauth_version=1.0&oauth_consumer_key=key&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_signature=t672hasdfdsfsdsdceVBFqKc>'. HTTP Headers: {
    Accept = "application/json";
    "Accept-Encoding" = gzip;
    Authorization = "OAuth oauth_signature=\"bEmMvO3sdfsdfsdfcdc\"";
    "Content-Length" = 31;
    "Content-Type" = "application/json";
}. HTTP Body: {"tel":"4344","name":"joaquin"}.
```

I think that everything is ok with that Request, the data is in the HTTP Body.

Meanwhile in the reponse:

```
   Connection = "Keep-Alive";
    "Content-Length" = 7;
    "Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
    Date = "Thu, 27 Sep 2012 12:34:08 GMT";
    "Proxy-Connection" = "Keep-Alive";
    Server = "Microsoft-IIS/7.5";
    Via = "1.1 ISASERVERSM";
    "X-Powered-By" = "ASP.NET";
}
```

My method return empty when the object is null, so the WCF is not seeing the data.

```
2012-09-27 08:34:05.056 RESTPRUEBA2[6698:fb03] T restkit.network:RKResponse.m:231 Read response body: "empty"
```

And im getting this error on the didFailLoadWithError

```
2012-09-27 09:11:25.500 RESTPRUEBA2[6698:fb03] error encontrado: Error Domain=JKErrorDomain Code=-1 "Expected either '[' or '{'." UserInfo=0x88d89c0 {JKAtIndexKey=7, JKLineNumberKey=1, NSLocalizedDescription=Expected either '[' or '{'.}
```

The funny part is that  i proved my WCF using RestClient addon in firefox with the same URL and data and everything worked fine.

Comment: You shouldn't put all your text in bold.

Answer (score 0):

This issue indicates that the JSON returned by your remote system does not parse correctly. The `JKErrorDomain` is from JSONKit, the JSON parser in use. Take your response body and validate it on http://jsonlint.com/ and fix the parse errors.

Comment: I validated the response that im receiving when i use RestClient in firefox and it said that is valid.

Comment: I'm having the same error and I haven't found a solution. I'm doing a `[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] deleteObject:user...` and the response for that (as I suppose, because Restkit doesn't say what it expect in the response for a delete) is empty. Like this: _The objectLoader finish with response: ""_